# How to Parse json array as key value pair where position is key in android kotlin

Tags: android, json, kotlin, parsing

I have json like below:

[image]

Here links as an array under values array. I have to get key and value from links array, like key will be 0 and value will be "http://www.example.com/....".

There may be multiple links in the links array like in 0 position, 1 position like that.
How to get this as key pair?

I am trying in the below way:

```
dataBinding.itemUserControlTvPhone.setOnClickListener {
                    val failedQtyMapper = jacksonObjectMapper()
                    if (data?.get(position)?.links != null) {
                        var jsonStr = failedQtyMapper.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter()
                            .writeValueAsString(
                                data?.get(position)?.links ?: ""
                            )
                        Log.e("jsonString:=", jsonStr)

but getting jsonString as 
    E/jsonString= ["http://www.example.com/reports/ Place Tp 2021-08-17 19_16_29_440.csv"]
```

But I need this jsonString as a key value pair. How to do this?

Comment: What do you mean with "as a key pair"?

Comment: I mean key value pair  @ Ivo

Comment: But what do you exactly mean by that? What type is that? Do you mean a `Pair`? It looks to me `position` is the key and `data?.get(position)?.links` the value? then just do `Pair(position, data?.get(position)?.links)` ?

Comment: I tried your way and it's giving output as,   E/jsonString:=: {
      "first" : 0,
      "second" : [ "http://www.example.com/reports/ Place Tp 2021-08-17 19_16_29_440.csv" ]
    }  @Ivo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since links is a list, each item in it will have an index from `0` to `list.size - 1`

You can do something like

```
   links?.forEachIndexed { index, item ->
        var jsonStr = "$index: $item"
        Log.e("jsonString:=", jsonStr)
    }
```